Regex for detecting arbitrary alphanumerics (with possible special characters in between) that are *not* purely alphabetical
Let's say we have a string with free text, most of which is words but some entries which are numbers or serial numbers or anything of the sort:
text == """My name is Maximus Awesomeus and my phone number is +13204919920, my sort code is 01-42-42 and my ID is ZUI8012IOI1. Here is a random string that shouldn't be caught: UHAHS-IQOEQI but here is a random string that should be caught IAIUH124242JOOO-1213IH/131IOIHIO"""

In a Regex search I would like to ignore all words and basically find anything that could be a serial number or number or anything of the sort. In this case that would be:
+13204919920, 01-42-42, ZUI8012IOI1, IAIUH124242JOOO-1213IH/131IOIHIO

I came up with this pattern:
\b(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z0-9._@#/-+]+\b 
But the look ahead, looks through the entire string and thus the purely alphabetical words get caught as well if there's even a single number in the rest of the string. I'm not sure how to get around that - regex has never been a strong suit.

Instead of using a word boundary, you could assert a whitespace boundary to the left.
Then instead of asserting a digit, you can match at least a single digit by excluding it first from the first character class.
The hyphen in the character class should be escaped or placed at the beginning/end
(?<!\S)[A-Za-z._@#/+-]*[0-9][A-Za-z0-9._@#/+-]*[A-Za-z0-9_@#/+-]

The pattern matches:

(?<!\S) Assert whitespace boundary to the left
[A-Za-z._@#/+-]* Match 0+ times any of the allowed characters without a digit
[0-9] Match a single digit
[A-Za-z0-9._@#/+-]* Match 0+ times any of the allowed characters
including a digit
[A-Za-z0-9_@#/+-] Match a single char from the character class without a dot

See a regex demo
Or shorter:
(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z_.@#/+-]*\d[\w.@#/+-]*\w


OP probably doesn't want to match trailing dot so suggest this: (?<!\S)[a-zA-Z_.@#/+-]*\d[\w.@#/+-]*\w

@anubhava Yes you are correct, I missed that. Thanks!!

(?:^|(?<=\s))(?=\S*\d)[A-Za-z0-9._@#\/+-]+\b

Your regex seems to be working fine with a small change.
See demo.
https://regex101.com/r/hX4jMa/1
The lookahead was spanning multiple words and that was the issue.

Word boundaries will fail to match starting +

@anubhava right!! modified.
